# Sum across multiple time frames using R

Tags: r

I have two data frames, x and y. The data frame x has a range of dates while data frame y has individual dates. I want to get the sum of the individual date values for the time ranges in data frame x. Thus id "a" would have the sum of all the values from 2019/1/1 through 2019/3/1.

```
id <- c("a","b","c")
start_date <- as.Date(c("2019/1/1", "2019/2/1", "2019/3/1"))
end_date <- as.Date(c("2019/3/1", "2019/4/1", "2019/5/1"))
x <- data.frame(id, start_date, end_date)

dates <- seq(as.Date("2019/1/1"),as.Date("2019/5/1"),1)
values <- runif(121, min=0, max=7)

y <- data.frame(dates, values)
```

Desired output

```
id start_date end_date  sum
a  2019/1/1   2019/3/1  221.8892
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One base R option is using `apply`

```
x$sum <- apply(x, 1, function(v) sum(subset(y,dates >= v["start_date"] & dates<=v["end_date"])$values))
```

such that

```
> x
  id start_date   end_date      sum
1  a 2019-01-01 2019-03-01 196.0311
2  b 2019-02-01 2019-04-01 185.6970
3  c 2019-03-01 2019-05-01 173.6429
```

**Data**

```
set.seed(1234)
id <- c("a","b","c")
start_date <- as.Date(c("2019/1/1", "2019/2/1", "2019/3/1"))
end_date <- as.Date(c("2019/3/1", "2019/4/1", "2019/5/1"))
x <- data.frame(id, start_date, end_date)

dates <- seq(as.Date("2019/1/1"),as.Date("2019/5/1"),1)
values <- runif(121, min=0, max=7)

y <- data.frame(dates, values)
```

Comment: Thank you this worked! I used the random values just for the reproducible example.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways of doing this. One possibility would be:

```
library(data.table)
x <- setDT(x)

# create a complete series for each id
x <- x[, .(dates = seq(start_date, end_date, 1)), by=id]


# merge the data
m <- merge(x, y, by="dates")

# get the sums
m[, .(sum = sum(values)), by=id]
   id      sum
1:  a 196.0311
2:  b 185.6970
3:  c 173.6429
```

You can add setseed before you create the random variables to exactly replicate the numbers

```
set.seed(1234)
```

Comment: You might want to check out the non equi join in the data.table vignette